# MPI code on Ubuntu have only one processor used

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi, processor

I'm trying to learn parallel computing with Open MPI. I use a Ubuntu 16 boot on a MacBook Pro.

I've installed OpenMP and try to run an `hello_world` to test it.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
// Initialize the MPI environment
MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

// Get the number of processes
int world_size;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

// Get the rank of the process
int world_rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

// Get the name of the processor
char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
int name_len;
MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);

// Print off a hello world message
printf("Hello world from processor %s, rank %d"
       " out of %d processors\n",
       processor_name, world_rank, world_size);

// Finalize the MPI environment.
MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I had no problem to compile it with `mpicc` but when I try to launch it, I've got the same result for `./hello_world -n 4`, `./hello_world -n 2`, `./hello_world -np 4` and so on.

It always writes:

> Hello world from processor ubuntu-mac , rank 0 out of 1 processor

I don't understand why can't it run on several processor... Do I launch it incorrectly or is it my config or anything else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are running it incorrectly, the program should be launched with `mpirun` or `mpiexec`, such that MPI can spawn the desired number of processes. Let's say you have your program in file hello.c, you can compile and run it as follows:

```
mpicc -o hello hello.c
mpirun -np 4 ./hello
```

Which should show the following example output:

```
Hello world from processor sagan, rank 1 out of 4 processors
Hello world from processor sagan, rank 2 out of 4 processors
Hello world from processor sagan, rank 3 out of 4 processors
Hello world from processor sagan, rank 0 out of 4 processors
```

Running the program standalone, as you seem to be doing, will only spawn one process, since the hello program does not parse the flag `-n` you are giving to it. `mpirun`, on the other hand, uses the `-np` flag to spawn the desired number of processes.

Comment: Thank you i didn't knew that :)

Comment: @ValentinMercier Remember to accept the answer if it helps you.